# Magento2 Moving minicart to sidebar removing ajax

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

this is my `minicart.phtml` file, now I've placed it in the sidebar it shows an ajax popup link instead of displaying the minicart itself. How can I edit this code to just let it show directly in the sidebar?

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
 <a class="action showcart" href="<?php echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="cart"><?php echo __('Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="counter qty empty"
          data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
        <span class="counter-number">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->0<!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
<?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
    <div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<script>
    window.checkout = <?php echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-block='minicart']": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    },
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
    }
}
</script>
```